# What is non-idempotent memory-mapped I/O meaning?

Tags: io, cpu-architecture

In [RISCV privileged spec](https://riscv.org/specifications/privileged-isa/) page 75 mention a term "non-idempotent memory-mapped I/O". What is non-idempotent memory-mapped I/O? Is it about non side effect?What is design concern about non-idempotent memory-mapped I/O?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means writing the same value twice is not the same thing as writing it just once.

e.g. an MMIO register where a write transaction triggers a UART to send the bits out over a serial port.

Unlike for a control register where writing the value that's already there has no effect.  Or e.g. a parallel port where the external pins reflect the bits in the MMIO register, and writing them again doesn't change anything.